# Convert ASCII to ASCII with different results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have a text file that I've received via FTP.  It's encoded as ASCII (verified with the vendor and checked it myself with a PowerShell function).  When I double click it directly from the FTP server and it opens in NotePad, the text file looks normal, which is, with the CR/LF.  When I drag the text file from the FTP server to the Desktop and then open the text file, it no longer looks right.  It appears the CR/LF's are gone.  So I created a copy of that file and ran this PowerShell script on it:

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\PowerShell\unknown.txt -Encoding Ascii | Out-File C:\Scripts\PowerShell\unknown2.txt -Encoding ascii
```

After running that, unknown.txt and unknown2.txt look different in NotePad.  Unknown.txt does not have the CR/LF and unknown2.txt does have them.

Why would this be?

Comment: What does _it no longer looks right._ mean exactly?

Comment: `Get-Content` parses line breaks (LF, CR/LF, LF/CR, doesn't matter) and uses them a separators to return a string array of lines in the file, after running `Get-Content` that information is lost. `Out-File` uses the default line break style in Windows. If you want a content-level copy of your file use a FileStream or `Get-Content -Raw`

Comment: What happend to actually answering questions? Comments != answers. :-)